# Is it possible to run Linux, Windows and Mac OS X on one machine in parallel?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, virtualization

I was wondering if it is possible to run all three big operating systems (Linux, Windows, Mac OS X) using a (preferable Barebone) Hypervisor in parallel on one system?

Please state the configuration that you are (expecting) to run this and let me know if you tested this configuration.

Comment: Since OS X can only be installed on Apple computer I assume you have one?

Comment: Not yet. But I am considering to buy one.

Comment: Not really worth it to run a Barebone hypervisor if you need OSX. I am currently running Windows 7, Windows XP, Ubuntu and CentOS in parallel, all on top of Yosemite on an iMac with Quad Core i7 and 12GB of RAM, and they run just fine, as long as I don't launch heavy programs. I am using Oracle's virtual box as well. With some hacking you can give exclusive low-level disk access to virtual box in a way that it uses real disk partitions. This wil significantly boost up the speed of your VMs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s absolutely possible and pretty easy to do. Since Mac OS X is a propriety operating system, I’ll assume you’re starting off with a Mac. I’m a fan of VMware Fusion but you can just as easily use Parallels or Virtual Box. They all come with easy to use instructions so I won’t rehash. One consideration is how much RAM and CPU cores to allocate to each system. I use the caveat of “just enough to get the job done.”

If you opt against using Mac hardware, you’ve complicated getting Mac OS X running by a factor of “it ain’t worth it.” I’ve never tried running a Hackintosh in a virtual machine but imagine it may be possible if you have the spare time and inclination for pain.

Comment: @JakeGould: Fair enough. That's a good point to make and thanks for the edit and the props.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, use Oracle VirtualBox and make sure you have enough storage (disk) space and memory to run these.

You can download it from the Oracle website, or try searching for "virtualbox".  And create virtual drives with the ISO files in the OS and boot in parallel.

Answer (score -1):

Use Virtualbox. Note you will need quite a beefy computer, as a Windows VM will take at least 1.5 GB of RAM, and you have to partition the disk.  This will take about 20 minutes if you have a good computer.